Python3 is unable to locate any of my installed modules
I am currently trying to work on a project for a course and I am using a python file to collect data using an API.
When I attempted to run my code this morning I was met with a ModuleNotFoundError when executing the file from my bash script:
Then to see if it was just in VSCode (which I am using) I went to my terminal and started python3 and tried to import the module:
trevormoy@158 Edstem-Tracker % python3
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr  9 2024, 08:09:14) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import edapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edapi'
>>> exit()

So, trying to run it in both cases results in an error.
Note: I have ran pip3 list and I have confirmed the module is in there.
I proceeded to try other external python modules only to be met with the same error.
In VSCode I decided to run the code with the Run Python File command:
button for running python file
When I run this the code runs completely fine but now I am trying to understand why my python3 is unable to find my modules.

When I first tried to try to fix the issue I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module I initially had trouble with. After realizing all my modules weren't working I moved to other types of fixes.

I adjusted my script so that it runs:
 /usr/bin/python3 "edstem/integration/get_data.py"

This actually ran my code correctly in the bash script with no errors. The only issue is that I need to account for Windows users that might use the project so, using /usr/bin/python3 won't work.
Because /usr/bin/python3 worked I decided to look in my bash profiles which appeared to be working fine. After I looked there I decided to echo my $PATH but was not sure if I was looking for the right thing. I saw that Python/3.9/bin was in my $PATH twice but I don't know if that matters in this case.



you have multiple versions of python installed on your machine, and whatever pip3 finds doesn't correspond to what python3 is finding.

Try using a virtual environment. This will isolate it from the rest of the system. To create one and make sure it works on windows do this:
py -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate
where python

For mac/unix
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/python
which python
.venv/bin/python

To exit venv, use deactivate.
Once you are in, install the packages, and they should work.
To reenter venv, use source .venv/bin/python for mac/unix and .venv\Scripts\activate for windows
